# How to include Switch Workspace in File menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am trying to develop an Eclipse RCP application but I have a problem. I don't know how to implement "switch workspace " in file menu.

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your RCP `ActionBarAdvisor` derived class you can create the Switch Workspace action with:

```java
IWorkbenchAction switchWorkspaceAction = IDEActionFactory.OPEN_WORKSPACE.create(window);
register(switchWorkspaceAction);
```

and then add it to a menu manager.

You will need to have the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plugin as a dependency.